# Concat DataFrame with specific columns condition into new columns

Tags: group-by, concatenation

I am very new to python and pandas.
I encountered a problem. For my DataFrame, I wish to do a sum for the columns (Quantity) based on the first column Project_ID and then on ANIMALS but only on CATS.

Original DataFrame
[image: Original DataFrame]

I have tried using pivot_table and groupby but with no success. Appreciate if anyone could help the debug. Thank you!

g = df.groupby(['PROJECT_ID', 'ANIMALS'])

concat1 = g.agg(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(subset =['PROJECT_ID', 'ANIMALS'], keep='first').QUANTITY.sum())

new_df = pd.concat([concat1.to_frame('QUANTITY')], 1)

new_df.tail(50)

Resultant DataFrame
[image: Expected DataFrame]

Answer (score 0):

Filter the DataFrame to get only the rows where "ANIMALS" equals "CAT":

```py
cats_df = df[df['ANIMALS'] == 'CAT']
```

Now, group the filtered DataFrame by "PROJECT_ID" and apply the sum function to the "QUANTITY" column:

```py
result = cats_df.groupby('PROJECT_ID')['QUANTITY'].sum()
```

prints the result:

```py
print(result)
```